# Driver transform channel for bone rotation

Tags: rigging, armature, drivers

I am trying to calibrate a rig to make animation easier.
I am using a driver on a calf bone with a transform channel variable to read the z rotation of a foot bone in transform space. For some reason, the calf rotation driver with the transform channel variable for the z rotation of the foot bone shows a different rotation value than the rotation value for the foot bone itself on the properties panel (N) in the 3D viewport. Its still off even if I update the dependencies. This is very confusing because the driver reads 1.920 z rotation while the viewport rotation of the bone reads 0.18 z. Where does the driver get this z rotation value if it's not what's typed in the transform properties panel in the 3D viewport? Is there a conversion I need to use to get matching values so it's not so confusing? The foot bone is using quarternions because I need to avoid gimbal lock. What should I do? Thanks for any advice.

Edit: So I realized if I rotate the foot bone 90 degrees, the driver shows a value of 1.5708 (which is correct in radians) and at the same time, the quaternion value for the same bone and rotation in the properties panel shows 0.707 which is exactly half of the square root of 2. So if pi/2 = 90 degrees in radians (which is what the driver reads if I rotate the bone 90 degrees) what formula can I use to convert the 1.5708 into (sqrt (2)/2) like the quaternion value reads for a 90 degree rotation in the properties panel? It would make it a lot easier  to write expressions if the edit values were consistent. Has anyone even ever discovered a square root number connection with pi? Unfortunately radians are based on pi and I don't know of any formulas that can accurately derive pi from a square root. I didn't delve too far into trigonometry as you can tell, but can someone explain to me why radians are based on pi? Why not 180 degrees = 0.5 radians and 360 = 1?

Comment: The values in the properties panel are in local space.

Comment: So I tried switching the driver variable to local space instead of transform space and it still reads different values.

Comment: ... what driver?, what variable?  If you want to use the property you see in the property panel use a single property type variable.

Comment: It is a single property type variable. I'm trying to access the values of a foot rotation FROM a calf rotation driver so I can copy rotations but the foot rotation value isnt consistent.

Comment: Sorry, this bone orientation rotational mapping is complicated and I have to explain better. I love and hate symmetry.

Comment: The degrees for the bone are correct, if I rotate the foot bone on the z axis 0.1 quaternion's, it moves 11.4 degrees and the driver reads the same in degrees. But the value number is off. What conversion formula do I need to plug into the expression box to make it the same?

Comment: `radians(11.4) = 0.1989`  [wiki explaining quaternion rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Quaternions)  Please edit your question to make it more clear using images and / or a sample file http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I just realized the driver "value" reading the foot rotation displays in radians. 11.4 degrees = ~ 0.1989 radians, but the quarternion value in the properties panel for the rotation is only 0.100 What formula can I use to convert the driver value (which is in radians) to the actual quaternion value in the properties panel? I know its  something along the lines of cos (45) * pi or something...

Comment: So if I rotate the foot 90 degrees, the quaternion reads 0.707 which is exactly cos (45) and the driver reads 1.5708 which is 90 degrees in radians. I need it to be 0.707 like the quaternion value in the properties panel.

Comment: [Conversion quaternion to euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Quaternion_to_Euler_Angles_Conversion)  Note that the 90 rotation on y axis changes both the w and y part of the [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Quaternions).